# TYPO3 8.7. Form prefill input field

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I use Sysextension Form on TYPO3 8.7 and want to prefill input field with get parameter. In Formhandler extension it was easy possible with Tx_Formhandler_PreProcessor_LoadDefaultValues. But how does it work on new form extension?

Thanks for help!

Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Stefan from Facebook - solution found on [TypoScript Setup Codebox für tx_form](https://www.riccabona.it/aktuelle-meldungen/detail/artikel/von-der-wiege-bis-zur-bahre/) - important is  renderables {   0 { -> where "0" is number of array index of field in yaml setup. So in my case the field for "datum" is first input field of configuration.

```
lib.objDynFieldValue = TEXT
lib.objDynFieldValue.data = GP:datum
plugin.tx_form {
    settings {
        formDefinitionOverrides {
            anfrageformular {
                renderables {
                    0 {
                        renderables {
                            0 {
                                defaultValue = TEXT 
                                defaultValue {
                                    stdWrap {
                                        cObject < lib.objDynFieldValue
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but if you reach the page with different querystrings it will remember the first that was transmitted. Seems like a caching issue. Reloading the page without cache works, but how can I avoid this?

Comment: maybe you can just add "?no_cache=1" to your link?

Comment: Or just put the whole content column of your form page (with condition like [page["uid"] == 512] ) in a COA_INT.