# Typo3 9.5 prefill form field with get parameter

Tags: forms, typo3

I use TYPO3 system extension "form" and want to prefill an input field with a GET parameter.

This [TYPO3 8.7. Form prefill input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294965/typo3-8-7-form-prefill-input-field) is working, but only is no_cache=1. Is there another solution without deactivate the whole cache?

Thanks
david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the cache of the content column of your form page, for example:

```
lib.content = COA
lib.content{
    10 < styles.content.get
}
[page["uid"] == 512]
    lib.content = COA_INT
[global]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to disable the cache for a single page with `config.no_cache = 1` inside the page condition?

Comment: That's also possible, but an alternative solution was expressly asked for. From a performance point of view and with regard to a possible use of indexed_search, it is also better if the remaining part of the page is cached.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but you need to create **HOOK**.

This is described in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/8.7/en-us/ApiReference/Index.html)

**For example, the HOOK**

```
/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\RenderableInterface $renderable
 * @return void
 */
public function initializeFormElement(\TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\RenderableInterface $renderable)
{
    if ($renderable->getUniqueIdentifier() === 'contactForm-text-1') {
        $renderable->setDefaultValue('foo');
    }
}
```

**And the connect the hook**

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/form']['initializeFormElement'][<useATimestampAsKeyPlease>]
    = \VENDOR\YourNamespace\YourClass::class;
```

Please, read the documentation for "Form framework".

I did it and get results what I need.

Comment: thanks for the note, but this don't solve the problem with the cache. How can i set the form to nocache to prefill a field, without deactivating the compleat cache?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks TYPO3UA for you answer. But you should use the hook 'afterBuildingFinished' because the 'initializeFormElement' hook is executed BEFORE the properties from the form definition are set in the form element. So the default values from the form definition (even it is an empty string) will override the values set in the initializeFormElement' hook.
See: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82615

So this works for setting the default value of an form element:

```
/**
* @param \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\RenderableInterface $renderable
* @return void
*/
public function afterBuildingFinished(\TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\RenderableInterface $renderable)
{        
        if (method_exists($renderable, 'getUniqueIdentifier') && $renderable->getUniqueIdentifier() === 'contactForm-text-1') {
            $renderable->setDefaultValue('Value');
        }
}
```

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/form']['afterBuildingFinished'][<useATimestampAsKeyPlease>]
    = \VENDOR\YourNamespace\YourClass::class;
```